# Does not have the required permissions to perform the operation and may have invalid credentials

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, deployment, google-compute-engine

I am new to using Google App Engine. I followed [this article](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/building-app/writing-web-service) to create a Python application. Then I am following [this article](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/building-app/deploying-web-service) to deploy the Python application.

When I run `gcloud app deploy` command in terminal, I got some errors. The terminal is as follows:

```
Services to deploy:

descriptor:                  [/Users/name/development/projects/python/app-engine-1/app.yaml]
source:                      [/Users/name/development/projects/python/app-engine-1]
target project:              [project-id]
target service:              [default]
target version:              [20221016t131330]
target url:                  [https://project-id.as.r.appspot.com]
target service account:      [App Engine default service account]


Do you want to continue (Y/n)?  y

Beginning deployment of service [default]...
╔════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
╠═ Uploading 0 files to Google Cloud Storage                ═╣
╚════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
File upload done.
Updating service [default]...failed.                                                                                                                 
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [9] Cloud build f5063328-5728-4368-80d3-885afb34bb6d status: FAILURE
An unexpected error occurred. Refer to build logs: https://console.cloud.google.com/cloud-build/builds;region=region/f5063328-5728-4368-80d3-885afb34bb6d?project=project-number
Full build logs: https://console.cloud.google.com/cloud-build/builds;region=region/f5063328-5728-4368-80d3-885afb34bb6d?project=project-number
```

The build log is as follows:

```
starting build "f5063328-5728-4368-80d3-885afb34bb6d"

FETCHSOURCE
BUILD
Starting Step #0 - "fetch"
Step #0 - "fetch": Pulling image: asia.gcr.io/gae-runtimes/utilities/gcs-fetcher:base_20220627_18_04_RC00
Step #0 - "fetch": base_20220627_18_04_RC00: Pulling from gae-runtimes/utilities/gcs-fetcher
Step #0 - "fetch": Digest: sha256:0e5bcbf16dccdca081070ee8bcdd14659dabc5b524f44902785ae36f6ae86d7e
Step #0 - "fetch": Status: Downloaded newer image for asia.gcr.io/gae-runtimes/utilities/gcs-fetcher:base_20220627_18_04_RC00
Step #0 - "fetch": asia.gcr.io/gae-runtimes/utilities/gcs-fetcher:base_20220627_18_04_RC00
Step #0 - "fetch": Fetching manifest gs://staging.project-id.appspot.com/ae/bfb86ea4-f91b-451b-9554-e560aa431250/manifest.json.
Step #0 - "fetch": Processing 729 files.
Step #0 - "fetch": ******************************************************
Step #0 - "fetch": Status:                      SUCCESS
Step #0 - "fetch": Started:                     2022-10-16T05:13:44Z
Step #0 - "fetch": Completed:                   2022-10-16T05:13:44Z
Step #0 - "fetch": Requested workers:    200
Step #0 - "fetch": Actual workers:       200
Step #0 - "fetch": Total files:          729
Step #0 - "fetch": Total retries:          0
Step #0 - "fetch": GCS timeouts:           0
Step #0 - "fetch": MiB downloaded:         8.71 MiB
Step #0 - "fetch": MiB/s throughput:      16.27 MiB/s
Step #0 - "fetch": Time for manifest:     56.55 ms
Step #0 - "fetch": Total time:             0.60 s
Step #0 - "fetch": ******************************************************
Finished Step #0 - "fetch"
Starting Step #1 - "pre-buildpack"
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": Pulling image: asia.gcr.io/gae-runtimes/utilities/buildpack-shim:base_20220627_18_04_RC00
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": base_20220627_18_04_RC00: Pulling from gae-runtimes/utilities/buildpack-shim
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": Digest: sha256:4ebffbd6a7a9f7924e10996be8effa965c085ac5d987f74768bf7805b490140d
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": Status: Downloaded newer image for asia.gcr.io/gae-runtimes/utilities/buildpack-shim:base_20220627_18_04_RC00
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": asia.gcr.io/gae-runtimes/utilities/buildpack-shim:base_20220627_18_04_RC00
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": Preparing directory /layers
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": Preparing directory /workspace
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": Preparing directory /builder/home
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": Preparing directory /builder/outputs
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": Preparing directory /platform/env
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": Passing build environment variable BUILDER_OUTPUT to buildpacks
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": Passing build environment variable GOOGLE_DEBUG to buildpacks
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": Passing build environment variable GOOGLE_RUNTIME to buildpacks
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": Passing build environment variable GOOGLE_LABEL_BUILDER_VERSION to buildpacks
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": Passing build environment variable GOOGLE_LABEL_BUILDER_IMAGE to buildpacks
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": Passing build environment variable GOOGLE_LABEL_RUN_IMAGE to buildpacks
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": Passing build environment variable GOOGLE_RUNTIME_VERSION to buildpacks
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": Passing build environment variable X_GOOGLE_SKIP_RUNTIME_LAUNCH to buildpacks
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": Passing build environment variable GAE_APP_ENGINE_APIS to buildpacks
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": Passing build environment variable X_GOOGLE_TARGET_PLATFORM to buildpacks
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": Passing build environment variable GOOGLE_EXPERIMENTAL_AR_AUTH_ENABLED to buildpacks
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": Retagging asia.gcr.io/project-id/app-engine-tmp/build-cache/default/ttl-7d:latest as asia.gcr.io/project-id/app-engine-tmp/build-cache/default/ttl-7d:f5063328-5728-4368-80d3-885afb34bb6d
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": Checking if image asia.gcr.io/project-id/app-engine-tmp/build-cache/default/ttl-7d:latest exists
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": Image asia.gcr.io/project-id/app-engine-tmp/build-cache/default/ttl-7d:latest exists
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": DEBUG: "asia.gcr.io/project-id/app-engine-tmp/build-cache/default/ttl-7d:latest"(asia.gcr.io/project-id/app-engine-tmp/build-cache/default/ttl-7d:latest) took 575.483695ms
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": Checking if image asia.gcr.io/project-id/app-engine-tmp/build-cache/default/ttl-7d:latest is valid
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": DEBUG: ...pull("asia.gcr.io/project-id/app-engine-tmp/build-cache/default/ttl-7d:latest") took 497.432054ms
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": DEBUG: ...validate("asia.gcr.io/project-id/app-engine-tmp/build-cache/default/ttl-7d:latest") took 140.527367ms
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": Image asia.gcr.io/project-id/app-engine-tmp/build-cache/default/ttl-7d:latest is valid
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": DEBUG: "asia.gcr.io/project-id/app-engine-tmp/build-cache/default/ttl-7d:latest"(asia.gcr.io/project-id/app-engine-tmp/build-cache/default/ttl-7d:latest) took 638.027643ms
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": DEBUG: "asia.gcr.io/project-id/app-engine-tmp/build-cache/default/ttl-7d:latest", "asia.gcr.io/project-id/app-engine-tmp/build-cache/default/ttl-7d:f5063328-5728-4368-80d3-885afb34bb6d"(asia.gcr.io/project-id/app-engine-tmp/build-cache/default/ttl-7d:latest) took 668.120881ms
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": WARNING: Failed to reuse previous cache image; will not affect current build: failed to copy image: GET https://asia.gcr.io/v2/token?scope=repository%3Aproject-id%2Fapp-engine-tmp%2Fbuild-cache%2Fdefault%2Fttl-7d%3Apush%2Cpull&service=asia.gcr.io: DENIED: Token exchange failed for project 'project-id'. Caller does not have permission 'storage.buckets.get'. To configure permissions, follow instructions at: https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/access-control
Finished Step #1 - "pre-buildpack"
Starting Step #2 - "build"
Step #2 - "build": Pulling image: asia.gcr.io/gae-runtimes/buildpacks/python39/builder:python39_20220925_3_9_14_RC00
Step #2 - "build": python39_20220925_3_9_14_RC00: Pulling from gae-runtimes/buildpacks/python39/builder
Step #2 - "build": 53e5e158da5a: Already exists
Step #2 - "build": c517f4e5fb00: Already exists
Step #2 - "build": 3c2cba919283: Already exists
Step #2 - "build": f2cee41d4207: Already exists
Step #2 - "build": eeaa92cc16f4: Already exists
Step #2 - "build": f3266cd4d580: Already exists
Step #2 - "build": 513371b2293b: Already exists
Step #2 - "build": 082adccced09: Already exists
Step #2 - "build": b935e8bb19ab: Pulling fs layer
Step #2 - "build": a855765f36b7: Pulling fs layer
Step #2 - "build": a57bfa4a8040: Pulling fs layer
Step #2 - "build": 195111d6a9d3: Pulling fs layer
Step #2 - "build": 60fec62a2730: Pulling fs layer
Step #2 - "build": 4e78a4178edf: Pulling fs layer
Step #2 - "build": 1296318fd3c9: Pulling fs layer
Step #2 - "build": 882401a7a06e: Pulling fs layer
Step #2 - "build": 06f428a8446f: Pulling fs layer
Step #2 - "build": dcaad5a887e8: Pulling fs layer
Step #2 - "build": a97726fa87f2: Pulling fs layer
Step #2 - "build": 5efe1d010cb7: Pulling fs layer
Step #2 - "build": 8e30c5c33f84: Pulling fs layer
Step #2 - "build": c8f9c9a33755: Pulling fs layer
Step #2 - "build": cba50fce0adc: Pulling fs layer
Step #2 - "build": 7770dd24cdc5: Pulling fs layer
Step #2 - "build": 4f4fb700ef54: Pulling fs layer
Step #2 - "build": 195111d6a9d3: Waiting
Step #2 - "build": 60fec62a2730: Waiting
Step #2 - "build": 4e78a4178edf: Waiting
Step #2 - "build": 1296318fd3c9: Waiting
Step #2 - "build": 882401a7a06e: Waiting
Step #2 - "build": 06f428a8446f: Waiting
Step #2 - "build": dcaad5a887e8: Waiting
Step #2 - "build": a97726fa87f2: Waiting
Step #2 - "build": 5efe1d010cb7: Waiting
Step #2 - "build": 8e30c5c33f84: Waiting
Step #2 - "build": c8f9c9a33755: Waiting
Step #2 - "build": cba50fce0adc: Waiting
Step #2 - "build": 7770dd24cdc5: Waiting
Step #2 - "build": 4f4fb700ef54: Waiting
Step #2 - "build": a855765f36b7: Verifying Checksum
Step #2 - "build": a855765f36b7: Download complete
Step #2 - "build": b935e8bb19ab: Verifying Checksum
Step #2 - "build": b935e8bb19ab: Download complete
Step #2 - "build": 195111d6a9d3: Verifying Checksum
Step #2 - "build": 195111d6a9d3: Download complete
Step #2 - "build": 4e78a4178edf: Verifying Checksum
Step #2 - "build": 4e78a4178edf: Download complete
Step #2 - "build": 60fec62a2730: Verifying Checksum
Step #2 - "build": 60fec62a2730: Download complete
Step #2 - "build": 1296318fd3c9: Verifying Checksum
Step #2 - "build": 1296318fd3c9: Download complete
Step #2 - "build": 882401a7a06e: Download complete
Step #2 - "build": b935e8bb19ab: Pull complete
Step #2 - "build": 06f428a8446f: Download complete
Step #2 - "build": a97726fa87f2: Verifying Checksum
Step #2 - "build": a97726fa87f2: Download complete
Step #2 - "build": dcaad5a887e8: Verifying Checksum
Step #2 - "build": dcaad5a887e8: Download complete
Step #2 - "build": a855765f36b7: Pull complete
Step #2 - "build": 5efe1d010cb7: Verifying Checksum
Step #2 - "build": 5efe1d010cb7: Download complete
Step #2 - "build": 8e30c5c33f84: Verifying Checksum
Step #2 - "build": 8e30c5c33f84: Download complete
Step #2 - "build": cba50fce0adc: Verifying Checksum
Step #2 - "build": cba50fce0adc: Download complete
Step #2 - "build": c8f9c9a33755: Verifying Checksum
Step #2 - "build": c8f9c9a33755: Download complete
Step #2 - "build": 7770dd24cdc5: Verifying Checksum
Step #2 - "build": 7770dd24cdc5: Download complete
Step #2 - "build": 4f4fb700ef54: Verifying Checksum
Step #2 - "build": 4f4fb700ef54: Download complete
Step #2 - "build": a57bfa4a8040: Verifying Checksum
Step #2 - "build": a57bfa4a8040: Download complete
Step #2 - "build": a57bfa4a8040: Pull complete
Step #2 - "build": 195111d6a9d3: Pull complete
Step #2 - "build": 60fec62a2730: Pull complete
Step #2 - "build": 4e78a4178edf: Pull complete
Step #2 - "build": 1296318fd3c9: Pull complete
Step #2 - "build": 882401a7a06e: Pull complete
Step #2 - "build": 06f428a8446f: Pull complete
Step #2 - "build": dcaad5a887e8: Pull complete
Step #2 - "build": a97726fa87f2: Pull complete
Step #2 - "build": 5efe1d010cb7: Pull complete
Step #2 - "build": 8e30c5c33f84: Pull complete
Step #2 - "build": c8f9c9a33755: Pull complete
Step #2 - "build": cba50fce0adc: Pull complete
Step #2 - "build": 7770dd24cdc5: Pull complete
Step #2 - "build": 4f4fb700ef54: Pull complete
Step #2 - "build": Digest: sha256:a74ace3651cc04f58b8f00abbbe44b422c35d65c838133e6e22d790e241df179
Step #2 - "build": Status: Downloaded newer image for asia.gcr.io/gae-runtimes/buildpacks/python39/builder:python39_20220925_3_9_14_RC00
Step #2 - "build": asia.gcr.io/gae-runtimes/buildpacks/python39/builder:python39_20220925_3_9_14_RC00
Step #2 - "build": ===> DETECTING
Step #2 - "build": google.python.webserver 0.9.1
Step #2 - "build": google.python.pip       0.9.2
Step #2 - "build": google.python.appengine 0.9.0
Step #2 - "build": google.utils.label      0.0.2
Step #2 - "build": ===> ANALYZING
Step #2 - "build": Previous image with name "asia.gcr.io/project-id/app-engine-tmp/app/default/ttl-18h:bfb86ea4-f91b-451b-9554-e560aa431250" not found
Step #2 - "build": Layer cache not found
Step #2 - "build": ===> RESTORING
Step #2 - "build": Layer cache not found
Step #2 - "build": ===> BUILDING
Step #2 - "build": === Python - webserver (google.python.webserver@0.9.1) ===
Step #2 - "build": DEBUG: Adding webserver requirements.txt to the list of requirements files to install.
Step #2 - "build": === Python - pip (google.python.pip@0.9.2) ===
Step #2 - "build": DEBUG: Found requirements.txt files provided by other buildpacks: [/cnb/buildpacks/google.python.webserver/0.9.1/requirements.txt]
Step #2 - "build": --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Step #2 - "build": Running "python3 --version"
Step #2 - "build": Python 3.9.14
Step #2 - "build": Done "python3 --version" (38.983437ms)
Step #2 - "build": DEBUG: Current dependency hash: "60abee411e5eddbf3072add8eb8ed0586fe520ff1f824e77e2ba0b04d2554477"
Step #2 - "build": DEBUG:   Cache dependency hash: ""
Step #2 - "build": DEBUG: No metadata found from a previous build, skipping cache.
Step #2 - "build": Installing application dependencies.
Step #2 - "build": DEBUG: ***** CACHE MISS: "pip"
Step #2 - "build": DEBUG: Setting environment variable PYTHONUSERBASE=/layers/google.python.pip/pip
Step #2 - "build": --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Step #2 - "build": Running "python3 -m pip install --requirement /cnb/buildpacks/google.python.webserver/0.9.1/requirements.txt --upgrade --upgrade-strategy only-if-needed --no-warn-script-location --no-warn-conflicts --force-reinstall --no-compile --user (PIP_CACHE_DIR=/layers/google.python.pip/pipcache PIP_DISABLE_PIP_VERSION_CHECK=1)"
Step #2 - "build": Collecting gunicorn==20.1.0
Step #2 - "build":   Downloading gunicorn-20.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (79 kB)
Step #2 - "build":      ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 79.5/79.5 kB 10.8 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Step #2 - "build": Collecting setuptools>=3.0
Step #2 - "build":   Downloading setuptools-65.5.0-py3-none-any.whl (1.2 MB)
Step #2 - "build":      ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 1.2/1.2 MB 60.7 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Step #2 - "build": Installing collected packages: setuptools, gunicorn
Step #2 - "build": Successfully installed gunicorn-20.1.0 setuptools-65.5.0
Step #2 - "build": Done "python3 -m pip install --requirement /cnb/buildpacks/google...." (1.624334285s)
Step #2 - "build": --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Step #2 - "build": Running "python3 -m pip install --requirement requirements.txt --upgrade --upgrade-strategy only-if-needed --no-warn-script-location --no-warn-conflicts --force-reinstall --no-compile --user (PIP_CACHE_DIR=/layers/google.python.pip/pipcache PIP_DISABLE_PIP_VERSION_CHECK=1)"
Step #2 - "build": Collecting Flask==2.1.0
Step #2 - "build":   Downloading Flask-2.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (95 kB)
Step #2 - "build":      ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 95.2/95.2 kB 11.8 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Step #2 - "build": Collecting importlib-metadata
Step #2 - "build":   Downloading importlib_metadata-5.0.0-py3-none-any.whl (21 kB)
Step #2 - "build": Collecting click>=8.0
Step #2 - "build":   Downloading click-8.1.3-py3-none-any.whl (96 kB)
Step #2 - "build":      ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 96.6/96.6 kB 16.6 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Step #2 - "build": Collecting Werkzeug>=2.0
Step #2 - "build":   Downloading Werkzeug-2.2.2-py3-none-any.whl (232 kB)
Step #2 - "build":      ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 232.7/232.7 kB 29.9 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Step #2 - "build": Collecting Jinja2>=3.0
Step #2 - "build":   Downloading Jinja2-3.1.2-py3-none-any.whl (133 kB)
Step #2 - "build":      ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 133.1/133.1 kB 21.1 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Step #2 - "build": Collecting itsdangerous>=2.0
Step #2 - "build":   Downloading itsdangerous-2.1.2-py3-none-any.whl (15 kB)
Step #2 - "build": Collecting MarkupSafe>=2.0
Step #2 - "build":   Downloading MarkupSafe-2.1.1-cp39-cp39-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (25 kB)
Step #2 - "build": Collecting zipp>=0.5
Step #2 - "build":   Downloading zipp-3.9.0-py3-none-any.whl (5.8 kB)
Step #2 - "build": Installing collected packages: zipp, MarkupSafe, itsdangerous, click, Werkzeug, Jinja2, importlib-metadata, Flask
Step #2 - "build": Successfully installed Flask-2.1.0 Jinja2-3.1.2 MarkupSafe-2.1.1 Werkzeug-2.2.2 click-8.1.3 importlib-metadata-5.0.0 itsdangerous-2.1.2 zipp-3.9.0
Step #2 - "build": Done "python3 -m pip install --requirement requirements.txt --upgr..." (1.919865752s)
Step #2 - "build": --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Step #2 - "build": Running "python3 -m compileall --invalidation-mode unchecked-hash -qq /layers/google.python.pip/pip"
Step #2 - "build": Done "python3 -m compileall --invalidation-mode unchecked-hash -qq..." (1.006248496s)
Step #2 - "build": Checking for incompatible dependencies.
Step #2 - "build": --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Step #2 - "build": Running "python3 -m pip check"
Step #2 - "build": No broken requirements found.
Step #2 - "build": Done "python3 -m pip check" (570.375607ms)
Step #2 - "build": === Python - App Engine (google.python.appengine@0.9.0) ===
Step #2 - "build": --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Step #2 - "build": Running "python3 -m pip show appengine-python-standard"
Step #2 - "build": WARNING: Package(s) not found: appengine-python-standard
Step #2 - "build": Done "python3 -m pip show appengine-python-standard" (393.179543ms)
Step #2 - "build": DEBUG: Using GOOGLE_RUNTIME: python39
Step #2 - "build": --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Step #2 - "build": Running "python3 -m pip show gunicorn"
Step #2 - "build": Name: gunicorn
Step #2 - "build": Version: 20.1.0
Step #2 - "build": Summary: WSGI HTTP Server for UNIX
Step #2 - "build": Home-page: https://gunicorn.org
Step #2 - "build": Author: Benoit Chesneau
Step #2 - "build": Author-email: benoitc@e-engura.com
Step #2 - "build": License: MIT
Step #2 - "build": Location: /layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages
Step #2 - "build": Requires: setuptools
Step #2 - "build": Required-by: 
Step #2 - "build": Done "python3 -m pip show gunicorn" (508.316899ms)
Step #2 - "build": DEBUG: Using config appstart.Config{Runtime:"python39", Entrypoint:appstart.Entrypoint{Type:"Default", Command:"/serve", WorkDir:""}, MainExecutable:""}
Step #2 - "build": === Utils - Label Image (google.utils.label@0.0.2) ===
Step #2 - "build": Adding image label google.builder-version: python39_20220925_3_9_14_RC00
Step #2 - "build": Adding image label google.run-image: asia.gcr.io/gae-runtimes/buildpacks/python39/run:python39_20220925_3_9_14_RC00
Step #2 - "build": Adding image label google.builder-image: asia.gcr.io/gae-runtimes/buildpacks/python39/builder:python39_20220925_3_9_14_RC00
Step #2 - "build": ===> EXPORTING
Step #2 - "build": Adding layer 'google.python.pip:pip'
Step #2 - "build": Adding layer 'google.python.appengine:config'
Step #2 - "build": Adding 1/1 app layer(s)
Step #2 - "build": Adding layer 'launcher'
Step #2 - "build": Adding layer 'config'
Step #2 - "build": Adding layer 'process-types'
Step #2 - "build": Adding label 'io.buildpacks.lifecycle.metadata'
Step #2 - "build": Adding label 'io.buildpacks.build.metadata'
Step #2 - "build": Adding label 'io.buildpacks.project.metadata'
Step #2 - "build": Adding label 'google.builder-version'
Step #2 - "build": Adding label 'google.run-image'
Step #2 - "build": Adding label 'google.builder-image'
Step #2 - "build": Setting default process type 'web'
Step #2 - "build": Saving asia.gcr.io/project-id/app-engine-tmp/app/default/ttl-18h:bfb86ea4-f91b-451b-9554-e560aa431250...
Step #2 - "build": *** Images (sha256:2f7d4915a978121c72581c9c3cb9e8f2b836a0376cabbb686f0e01815d917ad5):
Step #2 - "build":       asia.gcr.io/project-id/app-engine-tmp/app/default/ttl-18h:bfb86ea4-f91b-451b-9554-e560aa431250 - GET https://asia.gcr.io/v2/token?scope=repository%3Aproject-id%2Fapp-engine-tmp%2Fapp%2Fdefault%2Fttl-18h%3Apush%2Cpull&scope=repository%3Agae-runtimes%2Fbuildpacks%2Fpython39%2Frun%3Apull&service=asia.gcr.io: DENIED: Token exchange failed for project 'project-id'. Caller does not have permission 'storage.buckets.get'. To configure permissions, follow instructions at: https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/access-control
Step #2 - "build": ERROR: failed to export: failed to write image to the following tags: [asia.gcr.io/project-id/app-engine-tmp/app/default/ttl-18h:bfb86ea4-f91b-451b-9554-e560aa431250: GET https://asia.gcr.io/v2/token?scope=repository%3Aproject-id%2Fapp-engine-tmp%2Fapp%2Fdefault%2Fttl-18h%3Apush%2Cpull&scope=repository%3Agae-runtimes%2Fbuildpacks%2Fpython39%2Frun%3Apull&service=asia.gcr.io: DENIED: Token exchange failed for project 'project-id'. Caller does not have permission 'storage.buckets.get'. To configure permissions, follow instructions at: https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/access-control]
Finished Step #2 - "build"
ERROR
ERROR: build step 2 "asia.gcr.io/gae-runtimes/buildpacks/python39/builder:python39_20220925_3_9_14_RC00" failed: step exited with non-zero status: 246
```

When I click on the link (https://asia.gcr.io/v2/token?scope=repository%3Aproject-id%2Fapp-engine-tmp%2Fapp%2Fdefault%2Fttl-18h%3Apush%2Cpull&scope=repository%3Agae-runtimes%2Fbuildpacks%2Fpython39%2Frun%3Apull&service=asia.gcr.io:) that goes to almost the bottom of the log, it shows below:

```
{"errors":[{"code":"UNAUTHORIZED","message":"You don't have the needed permissions to perform this operation, and you may have invalid credentials. To authenticate your request, follow the steps in: https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication"}]}
```

I clicked the link and looked and it seems to be talking about key files, but I've done these things with key files before (maybe I'm overlooking something unrelated to key files).

Source code (Google team's source code because mine is 100% identical to Google team's code):
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/tree/2f10c77e5247eaf6237915311e1d98cb3dae1701/appengine/standard_python3/building-an-app/building-an-app-1

How to fix this error and deploy successfully? I would appreciate if someone could help me with a successful deployment. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Try: `gcloud auth login`

Comment: "project-id" is a redacted name of your project ID or the real value that you put?

Comment: Hi @guillaumeblaquiere I just replaced the real project id with the generic id above

Comment: I've managed to deploy the sample project using the links you provided without any issues. Also the error message that you got is for Container Registry. Can you provide the step-by-step procedure that you perform as I wasn't able to replicate the error you get?